# How can I solve Pandas/Numpy datetime error: numpy.datetime64

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am new in this area. I just want to concatenation of two tables with the date.

The test is my other table. I want to concatenation the test and usd tables in the data table.

```
data = test                                 
for x in data.index.values:
    for x2 in usd.index.values:                                             
       if x == x2:                                                                                  
            np.where(usd.index==x2)
            val = usd.at[x2,"Price"]
            data.at[x,"Price"] = val
```

I get his errors

[image: 1]

I try this **usd["new_time"] = np.datetime64(usd["new_time"])** this code gets some other errors and
**usd["new_time"] = np.datetime64(usd["new_time"])** this code run but it does not solve the problem
I get the same errors

My tables looks like these

[image: 2]

Comment: The information page for the pandas tag (stackoverflow.com/tags/pandas/info) has a prominent link to a question titled, "How to make good reproducible pandas examples". I suggest you read through that questing and its answers, the revise this question accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a join to solve this problem.
I cannot give you the exact answer as it would depend on the content of both your dataframes but based on the given information the following should work.

```
data.join(usd,how='left')
```

depending on your dataframe you might have to change the 'how' argument of the join() method.